# Can I have defaults for parameters in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following function:

```
public ActionResult Index(string caller_id, int? id)
{
```

Now I am using the following code to set a value:

```
var _id = id.HasValue ? (int) id : 0;
```

Is it possible for me to make the value of id default to something when the function is called without id being set?

Thanks,

Alison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but only if you use .net 4.0+

```
public ActionResult Index(string caller_id, int id = 0)
```

[Named and Optional Arguments (@msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: I am using net 4.0. I tried your method and it works but then I have problems with the code later when I do things like: 

 id.ToString("D4");   This gives me an error message :-(

Comment: @Alison Harvey: what actual message do you get?

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: I bet OP just passes `null` or some nullable type, thus get error of wrong type.

Comment: @Alison: It is customary when asking for help with an error to provide some clue as to what the error is. Make sense?

Comment: @zerkms wouldn't that result as a compiler error at the position of the fucntion call instead of at the ToString()?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am just testing stuff out. I get "no overload for method ToString takes one argument. I think the problem is that I am passing something that allows a null to a string. string int?.ToString()

Comment: @Alison Harvey: yes. Not you should pass either integer or null. Not a nullable int.

Comment: I just realized I was still using int?   Now I took that out and it works. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C# 4.0 or later, you can specify a default value for arguments not specified by the caller.

```
public ActionResult Index(string caller_id, int id = 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that this code doesn't use nullable types as your code does. That's not necessary unless there is no default value that could never appear as a valid value.

Answer (score 3):

The "old school" way to do that would be with an overload.

```
public ActionResult Index(string caller_id)
{
   return Index(caller_id, 0);
}

public ActionResult Index(string caller_id, int id)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: acutally I would not do that since it is cluttering the code more than really necessary, but technically yes!

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: for pre 4.0 it was a good enough solution. At least it is a great example of what reloading was invented for.